# Нужна помощь не могу вывести картинку из бд с помощью Ajax. Текс выводит, а картинку нет. Укажите на ошибку

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// code to get all records from table via select box
$("#employee").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = 'empid='+ id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getEmployee.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(employeeData) {
           if(employeeData) {
                $("#heading").show();
                $("#no_records").hide();
                $("#emp_name").text(employeeData.employee_name);
                $("#emp_photo").load(employeeData.employee_photo);//здесь фото
                $("#emp_salary").text(employeeData.employee_salary);
                $("#records").show();
            } else {
                $("#heading").hide();
                $("#records").hide();
                $("#no_records").show();
            }
        }
    });
})
```

});

---

```
      <?php
     include_once("db_connect.php");
     if($_REQUEST['empid']) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_photo FROM 
     employee WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". 
     mysqli_error($conn));

    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
?>
```

---

Вот сюда все это дело выводится

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>
    <select id="employee">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Employee Name</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee LIMIT 10";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["employee_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="display">

        <div class="row" id="heading" style="display:none;"><h3><div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Employee Name
        </strong></div><div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Age</strong>
        </div><div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Salary</strong></div></h3>
    </div><br>

        <div class="row" id="records"><div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_name"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_photo"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_salary"></div></div>
        <div class="row" id="no_records"><div class="col-sm-4">Plese select employee name to view details</div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "//здесь фото" - это что значит? `console.log(employeeData.employee_photo);`

Comment: что находится в `employeeData.employee_photo`? Если путь, то нужно что-то типа `$("#emp_photo").append('<img src="'+employeeData.employee_photo+'">);`

Comment: @MedvedevDev разница - три секунды :)

Comment: @Igor, вопрос был очевиден, странно, что нас только двое xDDD

Comment: `load` выполняет очередной аякс запрос по переданному URL, мб вам просто `$("$emp_photo").attr('src', employeeData.employee_photo)` надо?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Результат не получил. Надеюсь на помощь. Посмотрите пожалуйста на код ниже

Comment: Вам ведь сказали. Добавите в ваш код в `success` строку `console.log(employeeData.employee_photo);`, полученным результатом дополните свой вопрос. И удалите свои ответы, добавьте этот код в свой вопрос( кнопочка "править" под вашим вопросом")